# Can I view Report developed in Access 2007 in Asp.net web page?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I developer a report in Access 2007 and i want to know if there is any way that allow me to view this report in Asp.net web page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an ASP.Net page but one possible option would be to export the report as a snapshot (*.snp) file.  Then you can embed the file into a HTML web page.

You would have to re-export the report each time to update it though.  Also the user would have to install the snapshot viewer on their PC [Download Link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b73df33f-6d74-423d-8274-8b7e6313edfb&DisplayLang=en&displaylang=en)

I think it still works with Access 2007 see [MS kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928357/)

The HTML code would be something like:

[image: HTML Sample Code]

For more information see [Automate publishing a report snapshot to the Web](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP052612171033.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect to Access just like any other DB, and display the data using a ASP.Net DataGrid.

Comment: Your answer seems non-responsive to the question. If I'm understanding it correctly, what's being asked is if a report created with the A2007 report writer can be viewed in a Web page. This has nothing to do with where the data is stored, and your suggestion basically amounts to "No. You'll have to start over." I don't know the answer but the whole point of the question is, I think, to be able to use the nice Access report output. Short of outputting to PDF, I can't think of a way to do it.

Comment: i want to view Report created by Access Report builder to be shown in Asp.net page